# Adding CheckBox causes Inflate Exception

Tags: android, android-checkbox, inflate-exception

I have a check box defined in the xml file for my dialog fragment. When the code is executed it causes Inflate Exception. I don't know what is wrong with the code. If the check box is removed everything works fine. The same exception arises if i use a radio button also.

Here is my xml File.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#6688AA">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="Sample Photo"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
    <!--android:textSize="18sp"/>-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/correct_face" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/error_face_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/error_face_2" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/error_face_3" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Upload Your Photo"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_camera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_gallery"
    android:background="#917528"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:text="Camera" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#917528"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:text="Gallery" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_camera"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crop_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/uploadImage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Touch the image to crop"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_default"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_gallery"
    android:layout_below="@+id/crop_hint"
    android:text="Checkbox"
     />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_CropImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        custom:fixAspectRatio="true"
        custom:guidelines="onTouch"
        custom:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_crop_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_crop_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Cancel" />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DialogFragment File

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_upload_photo, container, false);
    Button cameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    Button galleryButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_gallery);
    uploadImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
    cropHint = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.crop_hint);
    mDefault = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_default);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraImage = null;
            try {
                cameraImage = Utils.createCameraImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "onClick: Camera file generate exception" + ex);
                Utils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Error Starting the Camera Please Try Again");
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (cameraImage != null) {
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraImage));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    });
    galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"), CAPTURE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });


    cropImageContainer = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container_CropImageView);
    cropImageView = (CropImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
    mCropSave = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_crop_save);
    mCropCancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_crop_cancel);

    mDefault.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Default",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Logcat message

```
com.realeffecx.styleu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.realeffecx.styleu, PID: 23411
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.realeffecx.styleu.fragments.wizard_UploadPhoto.onCreateView(wizard_UploadPhoto.java:107)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1988)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:754)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1614)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:633)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.realeffecx.styleu.fragments.wizard_UploadPhoto.onCreateView(wizard_UploadPhoto.java:107)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1988)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:754)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1614)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:633)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Cause
```

It's pretty much textbook stuff so i don't know what i am doing wrong.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you also post part of the logcat?

Comment: Where in the code do you use the checkbox?

Comment: added logcat message. Thanks for your reply

Comment: remove `android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_gallery"` and then try again

Comment: Text color of checkbox just check it.. its wrong

Comment: is it OK to add both `android:layout_alignLeft` and `android:layout_alignStart` for the same view? i think in some cases this might make a conflict (as start means right or left based on locale) and left always means left! not sure if this is the issue, but i think it's not right to have them both

Comment: what's wrong with Text color @DJphy?

Comment: @Yazan yes it's ok to add both

Comment: i think it needs resId .. let it be directed to values in color.. Sometimes they behave crazyly these xml..

Comment: @DJphy its hex color for black. Still  I tried after removing it and the error remains the same

Comment: That is not necessary. you can also apply textColor like this.

Comment: @vrundpurohit removed it and the result is same

Comment: `Binary XML file line #104: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton` and you're not using `RadioButton` at all. I say you should do a clean and then build.

Comment: clean rebuild and run.. that is what i can say..

Comment: Regarding your last 4 views you inflate, I can't find those ids in your layout. Am I missing something here? Can't find relative layout with id `container_CropImageView`

Comment: @EgorN sorry my mistake i accidently copied the error from trying with radiobutton. Changed the logcat wiht correct error message.

Comment: which is your 107th line in java class

Comment: @gj_ added my complete XML file

Comment: @vrundpurohit         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_upload_photo, container, false);

Comment: I think.. ummm... change `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_gallery"` to `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_gallery"` Remove that `+`.

Comment: @vrundpurohit tried that but still no change

Comment: I don't know man... not solution but you can do this. remove checkbox from xml -> clean -> build -> Run. if it works fine, add checkbox again. in my case this works everytime

Comment: @vrundpurohit  without the checkbox everything workfs fine. But if i add the check box back then exception arises.

Comment: @UnnikrishnanMR I don't mean to be rude with my question but, you put your `container_CropImageView` in a separate file right?

Comment: @UnnikrishnanMR I copied and pasted your xml and it has structure errors

Comment: @gj_ No its there i the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved the issue. The Inflate Exception was arising from InvokeTargetException which in turn was due to ResourceNotFoundException. The error was in the android support library 23.2. I don't know clearly why but google has renamed and removed some xml files from their support library and are using Vectors instead of PNG's. The error can be solved simply by reverting to the previous library (23.1.1) or using AppCombatRadioButton or AppCombatCheckBox instead of RadioButton and CheckBox respectively. If anyone else is facing the same issue you can check out this issue opened in google code https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202144

Answer (score 0):

Your first view in the Relative Layout seems to be wrong as per the layout xml code above (assuming you have pasted as is from file). `android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"` should be removed. 
I wonder how could you compile ?

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Upload Your Photo"
android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Just check.

Comment: I have added my complete XML file please check again

Comment: Please check if you have really missed closing tag for `</ RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: Its there i missed it while copying

Comment: as per i know, inflation exception is just as wrapper exception, and the real cause is below in the logs. Check what line of code comes @107 in activity. Also debug with breakpoints there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an invalid attribute:

```
android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

After removing it all worked fine. I guess the error should be more explanatory.